# Change Text Colour in MultiRow Text Box

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My client wants to be able to change part of Text colour in textbox.
I am not sure how to do it.

I have got a web form for a user to fill it. [image: Form to be filled]

But my client wants to change text colour. Not all the text. some part of it. And just 3 colour totoal. Black, Blue and Red.

Something Like this.

[image]

User can choose colour and type. Then choose another colour and type again..
But It is very difficult. I don't know where to start and how to do it... I need to save the start of colour and the end point.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Use a WYSIWYG JavaScript plugin like CKEditor.

Comment: You can't do that in a standard `text` or `textarea` `input` HTML element, but you could use `contenteditable` and roll your own, or find a third party control to use.